# как сформировать многомерный json код на php

Tags: php, json, api, json-encode

возникла необходимость вывести произвольную таксономию в json.

вывожу их так:

```
foreach($terms as $city) {
$city_name = $city->name;
$city_id = $city->term_id;
echo $city_name. ': '. $city_id;
}
```

но как мне превратить результат работы этого цикла в json формат такого  вида?

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "city_id": 1,
      "city_name": "Москва"
    },
    {
      "city_id": 2,
      "city_name": "Волгоград"
    }
  ],
  "pagination": {
    "more": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Собирайте многомерный массив из ваших свойств объекта `$city`, вы можете делать разного уровня массивы, добавляя `[]` - увеличим вложенность, максимальное количество уровней вложенности `255`.

За каждый проход, новый массив, вида:

```
$array['city_id'] = $city->term_id;
$array['city_name'] = $city->name;
$array['loc']['x'] = 10;
$array['loc']['y'] = 10;
```

Вы конечно можете и так написать:

```
$array = [
   'city_id'=> $city->term_id,
   'city_name' => $city->name,
   'loc' => [
       'x' => 10,
       'y' => 10
    ]
];
```

А после - воспользоваться функцией:

```
$array = json_encode($array);
```

И получим результат:

```
{
    "city_id":1,
    "city_name":"Name",
    "loc":{
        "x":10,
        "y":10
    }
}
```